# Best practices to prevent changes to certain files in perforce

Tags: perforce

What is a good way to prevent people from submitting changes to a file? I was thinking of two methods

1. `p4 trigger` with a python snippet that holds a dictionary with protected paths and warn the user that changes are not accepted any more for that file.
2. use a `bot` account to check-out the file and never check-in (sounds like a bad idea)

I was searching for  ["permanently lock file"](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3114) however that is just to keep exclusive locks when a file is only to be authored by one user at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `write` access in the protection table.  I.e. run `p4 protect` and then set up permissions for the path like:

```
write user * * -//depot/whatever/path/...
```

If you want users to be able to sync and/or open the file but not submit it, add another line afterward that grants `read` or `open` permission specifically.  For example, to allow users to `sync` that path but not `edit` or `submit` you'd do:

```
write user * * -//depot/whatever/path/...
read  user * *  //depot/whatever/path/...
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, how would the other lines look like? `open user * * -//depot/whatever/path/...`
?

Comment: If you want to re-grant permission, you'd add another line that doesn't start with a minus sign.  Updated answer with an example.